# Is it permissible to take donations for a free app?

Tags: halal-haram, software

I have made some apps which are completely free to download and use.
Is it OK to allow users to donate to me for my work, at no benefit to them?

The reason I'm in doubt is because the users who donate do not get any extra features or anything compared to those who do not.

So surely it isn't earned money, right? Or is it OK?

Answer (score 1):

Donation is exactly what is called Hibbah (هبه) in Islam.

There's no problem giving donation from people (because they decide to donate by their own) and they can't ask to return money because you gave them the application instead of money.

Reference: [Tahrirol Vasilah](http://lib.eshia.ir/21010/2/58/%D8%AA%D9%85%D8%AA) pages 56 to 58

Answer (score 0):

There shouldn't be problem if they do it as a wanted act. Since they are not forced to do it, then apparently it doesn't make any problem.