# Is receiving donations over the web halal?

Tags: halal-haram, money, internet

I am providing web services to many users, and develop a web portal where users can use my web products and web app free of cost for personal and commercial use.

Now I want to add a donate button to my web page so that user can donate a nominal amount to me for my work.

**`NOTE`** I just want to know that amount is halal for me?
If some one tries to help me to do more free work and donate me is this halal or not?
OR Should I change the name of button donate to **GIFT** or something like?

I also read this [Question](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/18583/is-it-permissible-to-take-donations-for-a-free-app) but I need an explanation can some one help me out to understand these type of donation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wa'alaikum Assalam brother!

Asking for donation is not a bad thing. You are doing something for people and if they pay you some money extra for your business, that might not be wrong in any way as its just like helping or supporting you. Unless any financial matter has interest involved in it or its related to haram act, then it is good enough to proceed with it.

Note: I am not a scholar, it is an opinion based on my knowledge about Islam, but I highly recommend to consult  scholar about this issue. don't fully rely on opinions of people who are not scholars, including me